# How to flatten a nested list in Vim script?

Tags: list, nested, vim, expand

I found some Vim list functions can not work as I thought.
For example:

```
let list0 = [1, [1, 2]]
echo count(list0, 1)
```

It returns `1`, but I want it returns `2`. So I think those functions can not deep into nested lists, only work on first level.

I think here I should expand nested list into a normal list like this:

```
list0 = [1, 1, 2]
```

How to flatten a nested list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
" Code from bairui@#vim.freenode
" https://gist.github.com/3322468
function! Flatten(list)
  let val = []
  for elem in a:list
    if type(elem) == type([])
      call extend(val, Flatten(elem))
    else
      call add(val, elem)
    endif
    unlet elem
  endfor
  return val
endfunction
```

Here `unlet elem` is necessary. Because the `elem` variable is **changing**, it is a list item, or a list, and VimL does not support assign a list item to a list, and vice versa.

Comment: Yeah, but I clicked the right answer twice, cannot change today.

Comment: No, it is necessary, because the `elem` variable is changing, it is a list item, or a list, and VimL does not support assign a list item to a list, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#reduce%28%29) since 8.2.0878:

```
let mylist = [[1, 2], [3, 4], 5]
echo reduce(mylist, { acc, val -> type(val) == 3 ? extend(acc, val) : add(acc, val)})
```

outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest vital.vim's Data.List.flatten as an another answer ;D

https://github.com/vim-jp/vital.vim